# Recursion and while loop for Python

Tags: python, recursion, while-loop

```
def rec_naive(a,b):
    while a>0:
        b + rec_naive(a,b)
        a=a-1
    return b + rec_naive(a,b)
print rec_naive(5,2)
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, but I keep on getting an error that says: maximum depth recursion exceeded.  I don't understand why this while loop won't work though because I put the count for the variable a.

Comment: Because you call `rec_naive(a,b)` **before** decrementing `a`. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Aside from your infinite recursion.  What exactly are you wanting this to do?

Comment: This is missing a [base case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions_of_recursion). (It will never return without making another recursive call.)

Comment: Additionally, your `b +` expression doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Thank you.  I understand what I did wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is even though you are trying to limit the calls with the loop, it cant get passed the first call, since its exactly the same as the starting condition. Try something like this

```
def rec_naive(a, b):
    if a < 1:
        return 0
    return b + rec_naive(a - 1, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check the value of `a` after each call of `rec_naive(a,b)` using the following code:

```
def rec_naive(a,b):
    while a>0:
        print a
        raw_input()
        b + rec_naive(a,b)
        a=a-1
    return b + rec_naive(a,b)
print rec_naive(5,2)
```

All the time I could see value of `a` is `5`, that mean that `a = a - 1` was never be called. Try out the following code:

```
def rec_naive(a,b):
    if a ==0:
        return 0
    return b + rec_naive(a-1,b)
print rec_naive(5,2)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense.

Comment: If it helped you, Will you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `while loop` would be an `iterative` way to multiply `5 * 2` which I presume is your goal.

Using iteration.

```
def iter_naive(a, b):
    res = 0 # variable to add to each iteration
    while a > 0: 
        res += b # add b each time through the loop
        a -= 1 # decrement a by one each iteration 
    return res # return total
```

Using [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) you need a base case:

```
def rec_naive(a, b):
    a -= 1
    if a == 0: # base case 
        return b # if a is equal to 0 we will stop and return the value of b
    return b + rec_naive(a, b)
```